# Require newline or EOF after statement match

Tags: parsing, antlr4, semantics

Just looking for a simple way of getting ANTLR4 to generate a parser that will do the following (ignore anything **after** the `;`):

```
int #i ;    defines an int
int #j ;    see how I have to go to another line for another statement?
```

My parser is as the following:

```
compilationUnit:
    (statement END?)*
    statement END?
    EOF
;

statement:
    intdef |
    WS
;

// 10 - 1F block.

intdef:
    'intdef' Identifier
;

// Lexer.

Identifier: '#' Letter LetterOrDigit*;
fragment Letter: [a-zA-Z_];
fragment LetterOrDigit: [a-zA-Z0-9$_];

// Whitespace, fragments and terminals.

WS: [ \t\r\n\u000C]+ -> skip;
//COMMENT: '/*' .*? '*/' -> channel(HIDDEN);
END: (';' ~[\r\n]*) | '\n';
```

In essence, any time I have a `statement`, I need it to REQUIRE a newline before another is entered. I don't care if there's 3 new lines and then on the second one a bunch of tabs persist, as long as there's a new line.

The issue is, the ANTLR4 Parse Tree seems to be giving me errors for inputs such as:

```
.
```

(Pretend the dot isnt there, its literally no input)

```
int #i int #j
```

Woops, we got two on the same line!

Any ideas on how I can achieve this? I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've simplified your grammar a bit but made it require an end-of-line sequence after each statement to parse correctly.

```
grammar Testnl;

program: (statement )* EOF ;

statement: 'int' Identifier EOL;

Identifier: '#' Letter LetterOrDigit*;
fragment Letter: [a-zA-Z_];
fragment LetterOrDigit: [a-zA-Z0-9$_];

EOL: ';' .*? '\r\n'
| ';' .*? '\n'
;

WS: [ \t\r\n\u000C]+ -> skip;
```

It parses

```
int #i ;
int #j;


[@0,0:2='int',<'int'>,1:0]
[@1,4:5='#i',<Identifier>,1:4]
[@2,7:9=';\r\n',<EOL>,1:7]
[@3,10:12='int',<'int'>,2:0]
[@4,14:15='#j',<Identifier>,2:4]
[@5,16:18=';\r\n',<EOL>,2:6]
[@6,19:18='<EOF>',<EOF>,3:0]
```

It also ignore stuff after the semicolon as just part of the EOL token:

```
[@0,0:2='int',<'int'>,1:0]
[@1,4:5='#i',<Identifier>,1:4]
[@2,7:20='; ignore this\n',<EOL>,1:7]
[@3,21:23='int',<'int'>,2:0]
[@4,25:26='#j',<Identifier>,2:4]
[@5,27:28=';\n',<EOL>,2:6]
[@6,29:28='<EOF>',<EOF>,3:0]
```

using either linefeed or carriagereturn-linefeed just fine.  Is that what you're looking for?

**EDIT**

Per OP comment, made a small change to allow consecutive EOL tokens, and also move EOL token to `statement` to reduce repetition:

grammar Testnl;

```
program: ( statement EOL )* EOF ;

statement: 'int' Identifier;

Identifier: '#' Letter LetterOrDigit*;
fragment Letter: [a-zA-Z_];
fragment LetterOrDigit: [a-zA-Z0-9$_];

EOL: ';' .*? ('\r\n')+
| ';' .*? ('\n')+
;

WS: [ \t\r\n\u000C]+ -> skip;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Thats exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Actually, quick question, is there a way to allow me to have newlines between statements and after the last statement? At the moment, they HAVE to be inserted straight after each other with no stray newlines.

Comment: @finnrayment Sure thing, done, see edited grammar above.  Cheers!

Comment: Thanks so much! If I could, I would be upvoting this again. Appreciate it. :)